# How to create parameter for "ICAM_Enterprise.xlsx" and 'Login_info'

Tags: ruby, cucumber

```
 def ()
    dir_to_excel = Dir.pwd + '/lib/config/data'
    read_workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse("#{dir_to_excel}/ICAM_Enterprise.xlsx")
    worksheet = read_workbook['Login_info']
end
```

I want to add parameter for ICAM_Enterprise.xlsx and 'Login_info' what will be the syntax for it? I have tried so many ways. I need to read excel because data driven

Comment: It's not clear what you need!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not clear on what you need, but here's a shot in the dark:

```
def worksheet(excel_doc_name, workbook_name)
  dir_to_excel = Dir.pwd + '/lib/config/data'
  read_workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse("#{dir_to_excel}/#{excel_doc_name}.xlsx")
  worksheet = read_workbook["#{workbook_name}"]
end

worksheet("ICAM_Enterprise", "Login_info")
```

Comment: I wanted to create a module and call the method but it's throwing error

Comment: Please don't leave code in comments.  It's too hard to read.  Instead, edit your original question.

Comment: I wanted to create a module and access worksheet method from any class

Answer (score 0):

module CF
def ddd

end
end

## then inside another class

class add
include CF
ddd
end

## also u have to add env file require 'CF'  # or folder name